# Entity Framework 4 - Sorting by foreign entity

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sorting, collectionviewsource

I get

```
'System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView' view does not support sorting
```

when I use the following CollectionViewSource:

```
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=CourseSessions}" x:Key="cvsCourses">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="StartDate"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

The DataContext is an `ObservableCollection<Course>`. I am using Entity Framework 4 and CourseSessions is a property of Course:

```
public ObjectSet<CourseSession> CourseSessions
```

How can I specify sorting in this case, short of sorting the data coming out of the database?

Comment: If the DataContext is already the CourseSessions ObservableCollection, shouldn't the Source property of the CollectionViewSource just be equal to "{Binding}"?

Comment: The DataContext is ObservableCollection<Course>. CourseSessions is a property of the Course class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that ObjectSet does not support sorting. Please, have a look to this article by Nicholas Romanidis: 
[Using a CollectionViewSource to display Master-Detail sorted EntityCollections](http://blog.nicktown.info/2008/12/10/using-a-collectionviewsource-to-display-a-sorted-entitycollection.aspx)